# XML Parsing unexpected behaviour LiScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I am getting unexpected behaviour from some jquery xml parsing.

I am getting the file from a server with the following code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "//path/test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) { //do stuff }
```

It isn't performing as expected, if I take the data directly from the file and hard code it into my JS it works as expected. The data within the file is in the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ProductRates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Total="64" Region="UK"><ProductRate><Description>UAE - Dirham</Description><ProductType>CUR</ProductType><CurrencyCode>AED</CurrencyCode><Rate>5.4427</Rate></ProductRate><ProductRate><Description>Australia - Australia Dollar</Description><ProductType>CUR</ProductType><CurrencyCode>AUD</CurrencyCode><Rate>1.6726</Rate></ProductRate></ProductRates>
```

So once I get the xml it is processed like so

```
var $xml = $(xml);
var $list = $('#ticker'); 
$prodtype = $xml.find("ProductType");
$prodtype.each(function() {
var self = $(this);
if( self.text() == "CUR") { 
    var 
        $CurrencyCode = self.next('CurrencyCode')
        $Rate         = $CurrencyCode.next('Rate')          
    ; 
    $( "#ticker" ).append("<li><a>" +$CurrencyCode.text()+" = "+ $Rate.text()+ " </a></li>");

}
```

});

I am using the liScroll js/css from http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html and it does work but the list items are stacked vertically and not horizontally across the ticker container.  Could it be how the xml file is being parsed?

The css associated on page run, hopefully helpful...

```
element.style {
background-image: url(test.img);
}
Matched CSS Rules
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
#content-header {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
}
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Inherited from div#shell
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
font-size: 100%;
}
Inherited from body
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
body {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #2f2f2f;
}
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
body {
line-height: 1;
}
currency_ticker_test.shtmlmedia="all"
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
font-size: 100%;
}
Inherited from html
currency_ticker_test.shtml media="all"
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the output from the browser? it might be css or the things are being dumped all into the one li.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml structure is invalid. You've got two opening ProductRates elements.

```
<ProductRates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Total="64" Region="UK">
<ProductRates>
```

The best way to check for valid xml is to save the output to an xml file and open in a browser.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo the file is valid XML.

Comment: Ah I see. Just added a comment above.

Comment: The items are output as 

<li>AED = 5.4427</li><li> AUD = 1.6726</li><li> BBD = 2.8524</li>

For example but they are stacked vertically, I assume it is a css issue but can't track it down.

Comment: You'd have to dump your css in your question for us to see what's going on. Sounds like the container isn't overflowing or your LIs aren't floating.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something to do with how the XML is being parsed as I've checked again and running it on the test server it's fine with a hardcoded XML string so I assume it's something that's being included on parsing the XML file which is stopping it displaying correctly...

Comment: Oh ok. It might need this then: $xml = $.parseXML(xml)